# AWS CDK ApiGateway deleting previous apis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have an api Gateway stack that simply creates the APIGW :

```js
// imports

export class BackendApiCloudfrontStack extends cdk.Stack {
  restApi: cdk.aws_apigateway.RestApi;

  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps & BackendApiCloudfrontProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const {
      ...// props
    } = props;

    // API Gateway
    this.restApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, `${gatewayName}-REST-Gateway`, {
      description: gatewayName,
      deployOptions: {
        stageName: 'prod',
      },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
        ... config here
      },
    });

  }
}
```

and in my other backend stacks, I'm calling a factory stack that calls the `createLambdaService` to create the lambdas and append them to the api..
The problem is that when I deploy different stacks, the elder apis get deleted and I only have the new apis.. is there a reason for that ?
Thank you !

```js
// imports

export const createLambdaService = (
  stack: Stack,
  props: LambdaBaseProps & DatadogApiKeys,
  role: cdk.aws_iam.IRole,
  AWS_ENV: any,
  api?: cdk.aws_apigateway.IRestApi,
): createLambdaFunctionResult | void => {
  ...

  const results: createLambdaFunctionResult = { lambdas: [] };

  const lambdaLayers: cdk.aws_lambda.LayerVersion[] = [];
  if (fs.existsSync(layersCodePath.modules)) {
    for (const layerName in layersCodePath) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(layersCodePath, layerName)) {
        const layerCodePath = layersCodePath[layerName];

        lambdaLayers.push(
          new lambda.LayerVersion(stack, `${serviceName + layerName}Layer`, {
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(layerCodePath),
            compatibleRuntimes: [baseRunTime],
          }),
        );
      }
    }
  } else {
    // if no layer code path, skip
    return;
  }

  functions.forEach((lbFunction) => {
    // imports
    ...

    const backendLambda = new lambda.Function(stack, `${name}Handler`, {
      functionName: `${name}-` + `Handler`,
      runtime: baseRunTime,

      // Code & Environment variables
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(sourceCodePath),
      handler,
      layers: lambdaLayers || [],
      // other props
      ...
    });


    // if API GATEWAY
    if (api) {
      const { routes } = lbFunction;

      for (const routeName in routes) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(routes, routeName)) {
          const element = routes[routeName];

          const currentPath = api.root.addResource(routeName);

          element.forEach((method) => {
            if (routeName == 'root') {
              api.root.addMethod(method, new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(backendLambda, { proxy: true }));
            } else {
              currentPath.addMethod(method, new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(backendLambda, { proxy: true }));
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }

    results.lambdas.push({
      name,
      lambda: backendLambda,
    });
  });

  return results;
};
```

Comment: You must not ever manage / change one resource in two stacks, period! If you want it to be in two stacks have the gateway stack know about the lambda instead but obviously do not in any way change the lambda in the gateway stack.

Comment: @luk2302 The resource is created in one stack and on top I'm adding methods.. But in other stacks I'm creating a different resource and different methods..